How to tell mktexlsr to use a specific directory
For test purposes I installed two versions of texlive in
/programs/texlive/2017
and
/programs/texlive/2023.
When running mktexlsr at the command line it only scans the 2017 directory. How can I tell mktexlsr to use the 2023 one?

Use the mktexlsr from the appropriate installation, it defaults the the search paths based on the location of the binary
so
PATH=/programs/texlive/2017/bin/something:$PATH  mktexlsr

will search your texlive 2017 tree and replace 2017 by 2023 to index the 2013 one.

Works like a charm, many thanks!
